# RESTFUL URLS in rails?

Tags: rest

Hi I'm building REST api for an app, I have a requirement in URL
such that url should be something like this e.g

`www.abc.com/api/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3.... and so on`

**There are cases**

**case:** The number of params are not limited it can change frequent

if today it is something like this

`www.abc.com/api/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3`

*tomorrow* it can be like this 
   `www.abc.com/api/param1/value1/param2/value2/param3/value3/param4/value4`

Is there a configuration where once you configure the url pattern 
   and every thing go smooth

and in `conrtoller` `params` should contain this kind of key-value pair
`{ "param1" => "value1","param2" => "value2","param3" => "value3"...and so on  }`

any suggestion  !! how to achieve this ??

Comment: Please extend the description of your problem domain further. What is this API supposed to achieve? Is it `GET` or `POST` and maybe give a real world example. From your description your requirement seems not to fit my understanding of a good RESTful API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your params are not fixed you can use wildcard in routing

for e.g
`get 'items/list/*specs', controller: 'items', action: 'list'`

```
def list
 specs = params[:specs] # e.g, "base/books/fiction/dickens" #split it and place in a hash
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails routing provides a way to specify fully custom routes with static and dynamic segments as explained in the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes).

Your requirement should be achievable with

```
get '/api/param1/:param1/param2/:param2/...', to: 'controller#action'
```

Comment: If I have n numbers of api then I have to write n times in my routes

Comment: That depends. Please give three example requests with different  APIs in your question to better understand your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `route scoping` for this particular kind of problem . In other way it is `nested routes`

More  details : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

This is a example,

`GET    /magazines/:magazine_id/ads/:id/edit    ads#edit

 return an HTML form for editing an ad belonging to a specific magazine`

I think this would be helpful for you.

Comment: I use nested urls , to achieve this, but there is a problem ..what if i need to add one more param then wat to do??

Comment: I did not understand your problem right now. can you explain it.

Comment: I did notice that. But you see,  you can not make a better digestive and easily  maintained rest api by putting more complexity on it.  you should break it down into versions.  and it can be looked like api/v1/ or api/v2/.  the thing is keep it simple and keep it nice

Comment: and make your api in development queue whenever you had to. keep it updated.